# Plugins/Gems/Libraries to get syntax highlighting for code in the browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting

I have a simple idea for a small web application that I'd like to build out, but it requires syntax highlighting in the same manner that [Pastie](http://www.pastie.org) does.  I was wondering if anybody knew what library (jQuery, Prototype, any) was used in the frontend, and/or which (if any) plugins/gems were used in the backend.

For reference, you can find an example of the syntyax highlighting [here](http://pastie.org/566242).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried [Radiograph](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/radiograph) which seems to work well using [ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/).
Ultraviolet requires [Textpow](http://textpow.rubyforge.org/) and [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/).

There is also [tm_syntax_highlighting](http://github.com/arya/tm_syntax_highlighting/tree/master) which wraps Ultraviolet too.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://blog.pastie.org/2008/11/refactoring-pastie-lessons-learned.html the Ultraviolet gem (http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/) is used.